# Screen tearing on rotated screen in 14.04

Tags: drivers, 14.04, intel

With up-to-date Intel drivers (HD4000) on Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity, rotating the screen `xrandr -o left`breaks the vsync and induces a lot of tearing (mostly vertical one when dragging a window), I get no tearing on a non-rotated screen.

The tear-free option seems disabled:

`$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep Tear
[    18.316] (**) intel(0): "Tear free" disabled`

But in 14.04, I can't find a xorg.conf with the intel device configuration to pass the `TearFree` option.

Comment: Could you insert a screenshot of the tearing? I didn't get this error message.

Comment: [xorg.conf to enable TearFree](http://pastebin.com/zbcCcnSx)

Comment: Are you using Unity? Unity should not require TearFree. This sounds like a bug, you should report it on Launchpad and on freedesktop.org (follow [these instructions](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/how-report-bugs)) There is also a mailing list ([details](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/how-report-bugs))

Comment: @bain I'm using Unity, I'll report the bug.